# LONG Blob innodb or MyISAM

Tags: mysql, blob

I have been doing reading that using a LONGBLOG with INNODB will have huge performance implications. Is this true? (I will be storing images)

Comment: There is a number of file-specialized databases

Comment: This is for mysql, is LONG BLOG using INNODB slower than MyISAM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know, but Innodb is pretty speedy and it certainly supports large blobs.  If you have you heart set on putting images in the database, I suggest you just try it and see how it goes.

I can tell you where people in your situation ultimately tend end up is to setup a separate filesystem for storage of large blobs (images, in your case) outside of the database, using the database to hold the metadata for these files.  Setting aside your performance question, it comes down to a matter of cost.  Database servers are expensive and critical: filling them with large amounts of data that can't be queried (let alone indexed) is just not a win.